# How can i use Now as a time filter in reports?

Tags: reporting, filters

How can i use Now as a time filter in reports?

I need to look at records whose scheduled time < Now.  How can i build this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US), `Now` is not supported in the Report Builder. Would using `Tomorrow` be sufficient for your needs, though?

**Update**

Idea 1: If reporting needs to be done on a more granular level than by day, you will need to resort to custom reporting and SOQL queries.

Idea 2: Use a formula field to extract the time portion of your DateTime field. You could then group records on a more granular level, depending on what you extract (e.g. hourly, within 15 minute intervals, etc . . . )

Comment: Today/tomorrow becomes a date comparison rather than date/time.  On call center metrics its critical to see what violation was made (in hours/minutes) which is where now becomes critical.

Comment: Like the ideas.  :)   The workaround i am thinking is to have a formula field to capture Now() - Scheduled time and have a filter on this field to see if its +ve .  If yes the user has crossed the scheduled time during the report run time.   Just wondering if i could avoid creating this field.  Also custom reporting is out of scope right now.